# FlowType annotation for React.Component state not being removed at compile

Tags: flowtype

So I'm trying adopt Flow into an existing repo and running into a roadblock when using it with React.Component. The [documentation](https://flowtype.org/docs/react.html#_) shows that you should annotate the state object of your component by placing at the beginning of the component. Doing this satisfies Flow and I no longer have any errors. However the code will not compile. Babel errors out when compiling this Component every time now. I have tried using the Flow support built into babel react preset as well as including the babel `transform-flow-strip-types` plugin. Every other annotation is removed without issue but for some reason this one is not. Is this a bug in the plugin or am I doing something wrong?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state: {someKey: {withSomeMoreKeys: string}};

    constructor(props: void): void{
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            someKey: {
                withSomeMoreKeys: string
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you have the [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) Babel plugin enabled